# How to build a Bridge and sync magento and zoho both ways

Tags: magento, integration, magento-1.6, zoho

We want to build a bridge to synchronize data both ways in magento 1.6 and zoho crm -to synchronize leads, quotes, invoices, clients (assign them a user id and password for our B2B website) -to synchronize products attributes, etc...

Examples :

- Each time a client fills up a form to be registered on my website it has to create a lead on magento like the first time login form ( i already made one web to lead form, but doesn't fit well with magento design and doesn't create the account in magento...)
- Each time a client asks for a quote (through a form "Request a quote") on magento, it creates an opportunity, or a quote (or a lead ?).

I would like something really simple that adapts to magento structure that's all, in fact, it's a question of pushing/pulling DB records in both softwares (magento and zoho).

So I've been looking all around the web, but if you google "Zoho Magento integration" it will only return people ready to pay for that. Since I know magento a bit, I'm willing to do it by myself.

Thanks for Your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a magento connector module to handle synchronization between Magento and ZOHO CRM API ( http://zohocrmapi.wiki.zoho.com/ ).

It is not easy. But if you have some experience with Magento development and do not know how to start with it, i would suggest you to download some similiar module (e. g. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/integrations/crm/erply-connector.html) and see how it is built. Then try to develop your own.